# Select DISTINCT individual columns in django?

Tags: django, django-models, distinct, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm curious if there's any way to do a query in Django that's not a "`SELECT * FROM...`" underneath. I'm trying to do a "`SELECT DISTINCT columnName FROM ...`" instead.

Specifically I have a model that looks like:

```py
class ProductOrder(models.Model):
   Product  = models.CharField(max_length=20, promary_key=True)
   Category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   Rank = models.IntegerField()
```

where the `Rank` is a rank within a `Category`. I'd like to be able to iterate over all the Categories doing some operation on each rank within that category.

I'd like to first get a list of all the categories in the system and then query for all products in that category and repeat until every category is processed.

I'd rather avoid raw SQL, but if I have to go there, that'd be fine. Though I've never coded raw SQL in Django/Python before.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

One way to get the list of distinct column names from the database is to use [`distinct()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)  in conjunction with [`values()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-fields).

In your case you can do the following to get the names of distinct categories:

```
q = ProductOrder.objects.values('Category').distinct()
print q.query # See for yourself.

# The query would look something like
# SELECT DISTINCT "app_productorder"."category" FROM "app_productorder"
```

There are a couple of things to remember here. First, this will return a `ValuesQuerySet` which behaves differently from a `QuerySet`. When you access say, the first element of `q` (above) you'll get a ***dictionary***, NOT an instance of `ProductOrder`.

Second, it would be a good idea to read the [warning note](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) in the docs about using `distinct()`. The above example will work but all combinations of `distinct()` and `values()` may not.

**PS**: it is a good idea to use ***lower case names*** for fields in a model. In your case this would mean rewriting your model as shown below:

```
class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    product  = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    rank = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: The method described below is now available in django 1.4 and is nice if you need ProductOrder instance with field aware distinct ;-)

Comment: I want to know how to modify this code so that it will work on `where` statements as well. Like `select distinct(app_productorder.category) from app_productorder where app_productorder.rank <30;` ?

Comment: How would you convert this into a normal queryset?

Comment: Nice tip on `select distinct on` in sql: https://www.geekytidbits.com/postgres-distinct-on/

Answer (score 99):

It's quite simple actually **if you're using PostgreSQL**, just use `distinct(columns)` ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)).

```
Productorder.objects.all().distinct('category')
```

Note that this feature has been included in Django since 1.4

Comment: @lazerscience, @Manoj Govindan: I'm sorry, you're right. It seems that I have patched Django to add that feature. I've added a link to the patch

Comment: This is now in Django SVN and will be in Django 1.4

Comment: Note: unless you're using PostgreSQL, you can't give distinct() an argument.  Best stick with the accepted solution above.

Comment: in the tests, this is `can_distinct_on_fields` which appears to be Postgres-only

Comment: It would be useful if the downvoters could explain the downvotes, the original answer was indeed incorrect but that was rectified about 4 years ago ;)

Comment: plus 1, but `all()` is not necessary here

Comment: This query not found on Postgres.

Answer (score 30):

User order by with that field, and then do distinct.

```
ProductOrder.objects.order_by('category').values_list('category', flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: Underrated answer! Would have been better if you have explained it better. I was facing a issue related to ordering.

Comment: I'm glad i stumbled over this answer, which worked, but why is this the case? I don't understand why ordering it makes a difference.

Answer (score 20):

The other answers are fine, but this is a little cleaner, in that it only gives the values like you would get from a DISTINCT query, without any cruft from Django.

```
>>> set(ProductOrder.objects.values_list('category', flat=True))
{u'category1', u'category2', u'category3', u'category4'}
```

or

```
>>> list(set(ProductOrder.objects.values_list('category', flat=True)))
[u'category1', u'category2', u'category3', u'category4']
```

And, it works without PostgreSQL.

This is less efficient than using a .distinct(), presuming that DISTINCT in your database is faster than a python `set`, but it's great for noodling around the shell.

**Update**:
This is answer is great for making queries in the Django shell during development.  DO NOT use this solution in production unless you are absolutely certain that you will *always* have a trivially small number of results before `set` is applied.  Otherwise, it's a terrible idea from a performance standpoint.

Comment: `values_list` does not put `DISTINCT` in the sql query, so this would bring multiple values if there were.

Comment: This is a terrible idea from a performance standpoint!

Comment: yep -- don't do this in production if you have a non-tiny table!