# How do you add the mysql query select distinct in python code?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to display distinct or unique values from my column/field `category`

The function from `views.py`:

```
def category(request, book_category):
    latest_book_list = Books.objects.all().order_by('id')
    return render_to_response('books/category.html', {'latest_book_list': latest_book_list})
```

I would like the line: `latest_book_list = Books.objects.all().order_by('id')`

To perform the mysql query:
 `mysql> select distinct category from books;`

I have tried using the `Books.objects.filter(category=book_category)` but it returns blank.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852104/select-distinct-individual-columns-in-django ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
cateogries = Books.objects.values_list('category', flat=True).distinct()
latest_book_list = Books.objects.filter(category__id__in = categories)
```