# How to list unique values in drop down list for Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

Just for testing, I have a Python that scripts that enters IP addresses into the database.

I have the following values:

```
127.0.0.1  
127.0.0.1  
10.42.1.42  
10.42.1.42  
10.42.1.42
```

Model:

```
class Invalid(models.Model):
    access = models.DataTimeField()
    ip = models.CharField()
    login = models.CharField()
```

In the template, this is what I have for the drop down list:

```
<p>Choose: 
<select>
{% for item in results %}
    <option value="{{ item.ip }}">{{ item.ip }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<button type="button">Filter</button>  
</p>
```

However, the problem with this method is that it lists all the values. As far as I'm aware, there is no way to create an array/lists although I may be mistaken.

Is there any way to only have distinct values show up in the list, that is:

```
127.0.0.1  
10.42.1.42
```

Comment: You really don't give enough details on what you are trying to do to be able to give a clear answer. What does your model (and database table) look like for the IPs?

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified. My model's name is Invalid, with the fields: "access" (DateTimeField), "ip" (CharField), "login" (CharField).

Comment: Look at the Django [Model reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/) and my answer below for which field types to use. You should use `IPAddressField()` for your `ip` field at the very least. I have edited your post to reflect this. It will need to be approved by a moderator for it to show up.

Answer (score 0):

assuming results is a queryset :

If you have a backend that supports (postgres) it you could use [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) on the `ip` field

`results.distinct('ip')`

---

[Select DISTINCT individual columns in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852104/select-distinct-individual-columns-in-django)

---

Maybe you could also build a unique collection in python

```
uniques_ips = {}
for item in results:
  if item.ip not in unique_ips:
     unique_ips[item.ip] = item

unique_ips.values()
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Django. How would I access the values stored in the python list. Should I create a new table for the unique IPs?

Answer (score 0):

In your `views.py` file you would subset your queryset to get the distinct values only. Then you would only return these distinct values to your template.

So, using your example, you have a context object called `results`. You don't define how you came to populate that object, or what your model looks like, so lets assume the following model for your application for the sake of argument:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ip = models.IPAddressField()
```

Now, lets take a look at `views.py` and here we are using [Generic Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/):

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class IpListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(IpListView, self).get_queryset()
        unique_ips = queryset.values('ip').distinct()
        return unique_ips
```

**Note:** You could also put the `distinct()` method above directly into the `urls.py` queryset object below...

In your `urls.py` you would make sure you route `IpListView` to your template. Something like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from myapp.models import MyModel
from myapp.views import IpListView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',
        IpListView.as_view(
            queryset=MyModel.objects.order_by('ip'),
            context_object_name='results',
            template_name='myapp/mytemplate.html',
        ), name='mymodel-ips'
    )
)
```

Note here how `results` is your context object name. This means that all your `ip` field values will be available in your template `mytemplate.html` as:

```
for r in results:
    ip_option = r.ip
```

And because you have already subset the queryset to only have the unique IPs, you get what you needed. So you just need to loop through:

```
<p>Choose: 
    <select>
    {% for item in results %}
        <option value="{{ item.ip }}">{{ item.ip }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button type="button">Filter</button>
</p>
```

One caveat here: you don't state if you need any other fields from your model. If you do, the queryset I listed above will modify the results you get, and you might not get back what you expect if you wanted to use other values entered to be returned...