# Double reverse lookup in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Consider the following definitions:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    a_obs = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name='b')

class C(models.Model):
    b_obs = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name='c')
```

let's say we have an instance `ob1` of type `A`. How could I do a double reverse lookup in order to obtain all `C` instances related to `ob1` without using the `C.objects` nor the `B.objects` managers?

Normally doing `ob1.b.all()` will give me a `QuerySet` of `B`'s, but what then?

Comment: Why can't you use `C.objects` or `B.objects`?

Comment: @mipadi because of circular imports.

Comment: Why not fix or deal with the circular import?

Comment: In worst case scenario I will but I would also be interested to see if such a lookup is possible.

Comment: A more dire concern than circular imports (which can often be dealt with by using the class names in string literals in FK field definitions) is IMHO readability and comprehensibility. Thus I've asked a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866755/chained-reverse-lookups-in-django-but-without-following-the-forward-relations) explicitly about following the reverse direction.

Answer (score 0):

Doing "double reverse lookup" costs a lot of resources. Are you sure data can't be structured any other way?

To answer your question I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236199/django-reverse-lookup-chaining-queryset) that might fit your requirements. Try doing:

```
# You start with object A as objA
objsB = objA.b.all()
requested_c_objects = [C.objects.filter(b_obs=b) for b in objsB]
```

I haven't tested it so it may contains errors, but hope you get the idea.

P.S.: Without `*.objects` is not possible doing it. Try adding your own Manager methods or do it in SQL syntax directly.