# Django model filter and do distinct by specific column

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have two models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name= models.TextField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

class Brand(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    name= models.TextField(max_length=255)
```

For example:

Category

```
         name        parent
         -------      -------
         vehicle        0
         car            1 
         motorcycle     1 
         truck          1 
         bicycle        1
         fff            0
         ....
```

Brand

```
            name      category
            ----      --------- 
            BMW        car
            BMW        truck
            BMW        bicycle
            toyota     car
            mercedes   car
            mercedes   truck
            someThing  fff
            ....
```

I want to create a queryset of Brand that is filtered by vehicle and to be distinct by name.

so I can create a form in my template  that will have a drop down filter with all the brands related to vehicle categories with no duplicate of names

```
            name     category
            ----     --------- 
            BMW       car
            toyota    car
            mercedes  truck
```

Is there any option to do it in a simple way,or do I need to write a function for that?

I saw an example
[Select DISTINCT individual columns in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852104/select-distinct-individual-columns-in-django)
but it returns a `ValuesQuerySet` and I need a  `QuerySet`, and I prefer not to use `().distinct('someItem')` that is supported only on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to avoid duplicates in your QuerySet is to add a [unique constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#unique) on the name field for both your Brand and Category models. This will stop the duplicates from being inserted in the first place.

The constraint will cause a IntegrityError to be thrown any time you attempt to create a Brand or Category who's name already exists in the database. You can avoid the error by using [`ModelName.objects.get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) instead of `ModelName.objects.create()`.

Comment: Its OK to have the same brand for different categories in the DB, but if I want to filter by brand the user doesn't need to see in drop down duplicate names

Comment: This joins brand and category, which can cause duplicates. A distinct will remove them at the cost of being slightly exspensive.

Category.objects.filter(brand__name__in=("BMW", "toyota")).distinct()


You can avoid the join by looking up the brands by pk and passing that in:

brands = Brand.objects.filter(name__in=("BMW", "toyota"))
Category.objects.filter(brand_id__in=brands)

Comment: I need to join brand to category as they are related. The user can add items to the system and when he do so he must choose only brands that are related to the category, so I display him the relevant brands related to the category he is in, And he can filter the items by brand , category , or category and related brand