# How to remove duplicate values from QuerySet?

Tags: django, django-orm

I write

```
users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True, article_creator__in=articles)
```

And I get `queryset`

```
<QuerySet [<User: A>, <User: A>, <User: A>, <User: B>, <User: C>, <User: B>]>
```

How can to remove duplicate values. I need get this `queryset`

```
<QuerySet [<User: A>, <User: B>, <User: C>]>
```

Comment: try `filter(...).distinct()`

Comment: This happens because of JOIN to articles. Turn this filter into `Exists(<articles subqyery>)`. Btw, this filter definition `article_creator__in=articles` looks like a mistake or badly named variable. Because list of `articles` (article ids) will be applied to `creators` (creator id). Which does not seem to be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `.distinct()`

So your new query will look like -

```
users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True, article_creator__in=articles).distinct()
```

You might also want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3853075/5911972) answer out.