# Filter out the repeated items of my queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In my Django project, when I query a QuerySet list, there have 5 same item unexpectedly, you can check the below snapshot.
if this is a Set, there should only have two items: (`SE01-A3`, `SE01-A4`)

[image]

this is my part of my test code:

```
qs = qs.annotate(letters=Substr('name', 1, 6), 
length=Length('name')).order_by('letters', 'length', 'name') # you can ignore this sort code.

    from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

    for a_qs in qs:
        jsonstr = model_to_dict(a_qs)

        print(jsonstr)
```

the output of the `print(jsonstr)`:

```
{'physical_server_model': 5, 'switchesport': 60, 'whmcs_tblorders_id': None, 'expire_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 30, 16, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'cabinet': 3, 'ram': 'Supermicro  DDR4___16', 'ipmi_account': None, 'intranet_ip': None, 'cpu': 'Intel Xeon E3-1230 v5', 'task': None, 'has_intranet': False, 'user': 12, 'id': 26, 'price': Decimal('1000.00'), 'customer_desc': None, 'trade_record': 126, 'name': 'SE01-A3', 'pay_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 30, 16, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'switches': 3, 'ipmi_addr': '172.16.30.3', 'ipmi_pwd': None, 'desc': 'ip: 43.243.33.25 【As】', 'server_status': 'active', 'disk': 'Seagate SATA___1000'}
{'physical_server_model': 5, 'switchesport': 60, 'whmcs_tblorders_id': None, 'expire_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 30, 16, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'cabinet': 3, 'ram': 'Supermicro  DDR4___16', 'ipmi_account': None, 'intranet_ip': None, 'cpu': 'Intel Xeon E3-1230 v5', 'task': None, 'has_intranet': False, 'user': 12, 'id': 26, 'price': Decimal('1000.00'), 'customer_desc': None, 'trade_record': 126, 'name': 'SE01-A3', 'pay_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 30, 16, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'switches': 3, 'ipmi_addr': '172.16.30.3', 'ipmi_pwd': None, 'desc': 'ip: 43.243.33.25 【As】', 'server_status': 'active', 'disk': 'Seagate SATA___1000'}
{'physical_server_model': 5, 'switchesport': 60, 'whmcs_tblorders_id': None, 'expire_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 30, 16, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'cabinet': 3, 'ram': 'Supermicro  DDR4___16', 'ipmi_account': None, 'intranet_ip': None, 'cpu': 'Intel Xeon E3-1230 v5', 'task': None, 'has_intranet': False, 'user': 12, 'id': 26, 'price': Decimal('1000.00'), 'customer_desc': None, 'trade_record': 126, 'name': 'SE01-A3', 'pay_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 30, 16, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'switches': 3, 'ipmi_addr': '172.16.30.3', 'ipmi_pwd': None, 'desc': 'ip: 43.243.33.25 【As】', 'server_status': 'active', 'disk': 'Seagate SATA___1000'}
{'physical_server_model': 5, 'switchesport': 60, 'whmcs_tblorders_id': None, 'expire_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 30, 16, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'cabinet': 3, 'ram': 'Supermicro  DDR4___16', 'ipmi_account': None, 'intranet_ip': None, 'cpu': 'Intel Xeon E3-1230 v5', 'task': None, 'has_intranet': False, 'user': 12, 'id': 26, 'price': Decimal('1000.00'), 'customer_desc': None, 'trade_record': 126, 'name': 'SE01-A3', 'pay_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 30, 16, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'switches': 3, 'ipmi_addr': '172.16.30.3', 'ipmi_pwd': None, 'desc': 'ip: 43.243.33.25 【As】', 'server_status': 'active', 'disk': 'Seagate SATA___1000'}
{'physical_server_model': 5, 'switchesport': 60, 'whmcs_tblorders_id': None, 'expire_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 30, 16, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'cabinet': 3, 'ram': 'Supermicro  DDR4___16', 'ipmi_account': None, 'intranet_ip': None, 'cpu': 'Intel Xeon E3-1230 v5', 'task': None, 'has_intranet': False, 'user': 12, 'id': 26, 'price': Decimal('1000.00'), 'customer_desc': None, 'trade_record': 126, 'name': 'SE01-A3', 'pay_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 30, 16, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'switches': 3, 'ipmi_addr': '172.16.30.3', 'ipmi_pwd': None, 'desc': 'ip: 43.243.33.25 【As】', 'server_status': 'active', 'disk': 'Seagate SATA___1000'}
{'physical_server_model': 5, 'switchesport': 62, 'whmcs_tblorders_id': None, 'expire_time': None, 'cabinet': 3, 'ram': 'Supermicro  DDR4___16', 'ipmi_account': None, 'intranet_ip': None, 'cpu': 'Intel Xeon E3-1230 v5', 'task': None, 'has_intranet': False, 'user': 12, 'id': 27, 'price': Decimal('1000.00'), 'customer_desc': None, 'trade_record': None, 'name': 'SE01-A4', 'pay_time': None, 'switches': 3, 'ipmi_addr': '172.16.30.4', 'ipmi_pwd': None, 'desc': '', 'server_status': 'active', 'disk': 'Seagate SATA___1000'}
```

Is there any way to filter out the repeated items, in my case only left my requirement (`SE01-A3`, `SE01-A4`) set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select DISTINCT individual columns in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852104/select-distinct-individual-columns-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip duplicates we have to use `distinct` method on `queryset` like below

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

qs = qs.annotate(
    letters=Substr('name', 1, 6), 
    length=Length('name')
).order_by('letters', 'length', 'name').distinct()
for a_qs in qs:
    jsonstr = model_to_dict(a_qs)
    print(jsonstr)
```