# prefetch_related as list of objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, orm

I don't know how to merge all refetch_related objects from MeasurememtResult table to one list objects:

models.py

```
class DeviceMeasurement(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    front_id = models.UUIDField(blank=True, null=True)


class MeasurememtResult(models.Model):
    measurement_result = models.FloatField()
    measurement_type = models.CharField(choices=MEASUREMENT_TYPES, max_length=30)
    device_measurement_id = models.ForeignKey(DeviceMeasurement, related_name='res_data', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
class GetMeasurements(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.ListModelMixin):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = GetMeasurementsSerializer
    queryset = DeviceMeasurement.objects.values('patient__first_name', 'device__id', 'created_date', 'front_id',
                                                'results__measurement_result',
                                                'results__measurement_type').prefetch_related('res_data').all()
```

serializers.py

```
class GetMeasurementsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    created_date = serializers.DateTimeField()
    front_id = serializers.UUIDField()
    patient__first_name = serializers.CharField()
    device__id = serializers.IntegerField()
    results__measurement_result =  serializers.IntegerField()
    results__measurement_type = serializers.CharField() `
```

So, I got Response like as:

```
[
    {
        "created_date": "2020-06-05T15:03:22.481032+03:00",
        "front_id": null,
        "patient__first_name": "Alex",
        "device__id": 8,
        "results__measurement_result": 100,
        "results__measurement_type": "blood_pressure_SYS"
    },
    {
        "created_date": "2020-06-05T15:03:22.481032+03:00",
        "front_id": null,
        "patient__first_name": "Alex",
        "device__id": 8,
        "results__measurement_result": 120,
        "results__measurement_type": "blood_pressure_DIA"
    }
]
```

But I should return list of MeasurememtResult objects like as:
In 2 objects i have equal values of device_id.

```
    {
        "created_date": "2020-06-05T15:03:22.481032+03:00",
        "front_id": null,
        "patient__first_name": "Alex",
        "device__id": 8,
        "res_data": [
            {
                "results__measurement_result": 120,
                "results__measurement_type": "blood_pressure_DIA"
            },
            {
                "results__measurement_result": 100,
                "results__measurement_type": "blood_pressure_SYS"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: please post your serailizer GetMeasurementsSerializer

Comment: pleasae edit the question ..dont post code in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefetch related is for database query optimization . It has no relation with how your response is structured .

To return queryset with distinct device id ,

```
 queryset = DeviceMeasurement.objects.all().distinct("device").prefetch_related('res_data')
```

Note that the distinct("fieldname") will only work if you using postgres database .Please research on how to get it working in your database.
[Select DISTINCT individual columns in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852104/select-distinct-individual-columns-in-django)

Then in your serializer:

```
class MeasurementResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = MeasurememtResult
         fields = "__all__"
         read_only_fields = fields

class GetMeasurementsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        res_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        created_date = serializers.DateTimeField()
        front_id = serializers.UUIDField()
        patient__first_name = serializers.CharField()
        device__id = serializers.IntegerField()
       
        def get_res_data(self, instance):
            return MeasurementResultSerializer(instance.res_data.all(), many=True).data
```

You can edit this with your required fields ,  Inside fields array you can give fields like :

```
 fields = ["measurement_result", "measurement_type"]
```